# Why is the textfield label purple in smui?

Tags: material-ui, svelte

I installed the [svelte material ui component library](https://sveltematerialui.com/demo/textfield/) in my svelte project. Unfortunately
the floating label is colored purple by the following css rule provided by the smui-package. How can I fix this?

css in dev tools

```
.mdc-text-field--focused:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-floating-label {
   color:rgba(98, 0, 238, 0.87) //purple
}
```

smui textfield

```
<Textfield bind:value={valueA} label="Label">
  <HelperText slot="helper">Helper Text</HelperText>
</Textfield>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the default `bare.css` stylesheet, probably as a CDN package. While it is possible to override *some* of that base theming using CSS variables, `Textfield` labels cannot be overridden that way. (If you're interested, see [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/29d3b76680d84bcea8621ca549f6c191?version=3.55.0) verifying that, in fact, labels are not impacted by changing CSS variables).

For that, you will have to [put together your own theme](https://sveltematerialui.com/THEMING.md), meaning defining your own primary, secondary, etc. theme colors, spacing, etc. (note: you won't have to override *everything*, only these values you want to change from the default behavior ; for instance, in your case, you can focus on colors and leave spacing etc. untouched).

Once your theme has been compiled into a stylesheet, use it as a replacement for the `bare.css` file (or CDN package) you were using until then. You can also dive into the details of the compiled stylesheet and manually change any of the rules you want.

My advice: experiment and tinker until you get the result you were looking for. You'll learn a lot in doing so. Good luck !